# What's the difference between P = 5V x 3A and P = 3V x 5A?

Tags: power

What's the effective difference between power(W) = 5V x 3A and power(W) = 3V x 5A?

Comment: Without any more context... Nothing. Why?

Comment: In an *ideal* (e.g. textbook) case, nothing.  In a *real* case, there are several considerations to take into account.  It would help if we knew more details.

Comment: Difference is having different voltage and current to achieve same power as a product of them.

Comment: Probably it's more feasible/easier/preferable to go with 5V and 3A, than 3V and 5A, assuming some things and ignoring some other things :) [tryna be as descriptive as the OP]

Comment: @Elementronics.  Thanks :)  Not sure but I'm guessing OP means Original Poster.  Just the other day I learned that electrons hardly move in a circuit, pretty counter intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

In a physical sense, there's a lot of differences to take into account. Let's — for the sake of example — increase one of the values by a factor of 100:

**500 V \$\times\$ 3 A = 1500 W**

Higher voltages require greater insulation and attention to clearance. In this scenario, the wires wouldn't necessarily need to have a large cross-sectional area, but the insulation would need to be rated for the voltage, and the danger to someone working around it is much greater than lower voltages.

**5 V \$\times\$ 300 A = 1500 W**

Higher currents require larger conductors and attention to thermal dissipation. In this scenario, the wire would need to be *very* heavy-duty to carry 300 amperes; something like 67mm<sup>2</sup> or greater. However, the insulation would not be as great a concern. In fact a person could touch the conductor as it is only 5V which is insufficient* to cause an electric shock.

In both cases, 1500 watts is the power being dissipated. One might imagine the load could be a heater of some kind, as it is quite common to find heaters rated for 1500 W. You could reason that the first case, with 500 volts, is inherently unsafe; and that the second case, with massive conductor requirements, is completely impractical.

The choice or balance between voltage and current isn't arbitrary. Depending on the application, you might want one to be much higher than the other. For example, power transmission lines operate at incredibly high voltages. This is to minimize the conductor size and losses. The danger is mitigated in a myriad of ways, including placing the lines at great height. Contrast that with an electric welding machine, where large amounts of current are used to fuse metals. In that application, large conductors are used.

<sup>** Barring unusual circumstances that bypass the insulation of the skin.*</sup>

Comment: At 67mm squared I presume it'd equate to a peperoni slice of 67mm circumference.  I'll also continue researching what's behind the 15A then 20A electrical box switches while just one cable comes in the house.  Also looks like going with the least amount of volts VS least amount of amps to generate power is the better option if you have the cables for it.  Can't help wondering about the methods used to set the desired voltage from power sources, like from dams.  Not sure how long before a question gets answered but I'll leave it on for another day see if anyone else wants to contribute, thanks.

Comment: @Flood how do you calculate the area of a circle? 67mm circumference is NOT the same as 67mm^2... Try just under 10mm diameter which is about 31mm circumference.

Comment: I don't, I presume instead.

Comment: @Flood 67 mm<sup>2</sup> is the cross-sectional area. It would have a diameter of about 9.3 mm (AWG 00). The second example was meant to help visualize having very large and expensive wiring for comparison sake. For future questions, be sure to search the site first (for duplicates). Feel free to ask questions to help clarify any confusion, but be sure to add details and context to avoid having your question get closed.

Comment: @JYelton Much appreciate your input.  My question stands on its own. Life's too short!